# Symfony 4 : problem with locale in Command

Tags: php, symfony4

I'm building a Symfony 4 application using locale.
My locale is binded in services.yaml :

```
parameters:
  locale: 'en'
  app_locales: en|fr|de|es|pt|

services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true 
    autoconfigure: true
    bind:
        $locale: "@=service('request_stack').getCurrentRequest().getLocale()"
        $listLocales: '%app_locales%'

    App\:
      resource: '../src/*'
      exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Repository\:
      esource: '../src/Repository'
```

Also, locale is injected and can be used in my repositories (used for elastic search request).

I need to add a command that uses one of my repositories to retrieve some data but I get this error:

```
In getSomeRepositoryService.php line 12:
Call to a member function getLocale() on null
```

var/cache/dev/ContainerJyByO4D/getSomeRepositoryService.php:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\RewindableGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException;

// This file has been auto-generated by the Symfony Dependency Injection Component for internal use.
// Returns the private 'App\Repository\SomeRepository' shared autowired service.

include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/src/Repository/AbstractRepository.php';
include_once $this->targetDirs[3].'/src/Repository/SomeRepository.php';

return $this->privates['App\Repository\SomeRepository'] = new \App\Repository\SomeRepository(($this->privates['Elastica\Client'] ?? $this->load('getClientService.php')), ($this->services['request_stack'] ?? ($this->services['request_stack'] = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack()))->getCurrentRequest()->getLocale());
```

Locale is injected in AbstractRepository constructor.

Here's my command (simplified version) :

```
classFooCommand extends Command 
{
    protected $someRepository;

    public function __construct(SomeRepository $someRepository) 
    {
        $this->someRepository = $someRepository;
        parent::_construct();  
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) 
    {
        $demoData = $this->someRepository->getFoo();
        var_dump($demoData);
    }
}
```

How can the locale get injected in my command correctly?

Comment: Because a command doesn't run in the context of a request, you of course don't have a request you can get the locale from. So instead of generally finding the locale to every $locale parameter, you should inject the `@request_stack` into your services, try to get the locale there and if there is no current request, use a default value for your locale.

Comment: I understand the problem :). Your solution is attractive but it will make a big refactoring for a little case-use, i think it will be better to copy the part of code i need into my command, also it's not very clean.